# React pass data from mapped child to new component

Tags: reactjs

I have a shopping catalog, I want to get data from the child and pass to a new component. I've mapped data from JSON (later to be an api call) and I want to get a few props from the mapped child component ie name, price, and the count (which is part of the component, not the original data)

data(name/price) -> mainComponent -> mapped to childComponent(has count)-> mainComponent

should I be using forms? some lifecycle methods? redux? Router? not really sure how to go about this.

Data

```
const marketData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "product1",
        price: "$2",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "product2",
        price: "$3",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "product3",
        price: "$3",
    }
]
```

Parent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MarketItem from './MarketItem.js'
import MarketData from './MarketData.js'


class MarketContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      market: MarketData
    }
  }

  render() {
    const marketItems = this.state.market.map(item => <MarketItem key={item.id} product={item} />)

    return (
      <div>
          {marketItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MarketContainer;
```

child

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';

class MarketItem extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
        count : 0
      }
}


IncrementItem = () => {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
}
IncrementItemBy10 = () => {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 10 });
}

render(){
    return (
      <div className="MarketItem">
        <div className="market__content">
            <h1>{this.props.product.name + " " + this.props.product.price}</h1>   
        </div> 
            <div className="market__counter">
              <button className="market__button--minus" onClick={this.DecreaseItem}>-</button>
              <p>{this.state.count}</p>
              <button className="market__button--plus" onClick={this.IncrementItem}>+</button>
            </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MarketItem;
```

Within parent (marketContainer) I want to get the count, name, and price from every child component, make a new component. I've tried forms, but wasn't really happy with that should I use lifecycle methods? redux? Router?

Comment: Perhaps you should render you `<MarketItem>` components with a callback prop to notify the `<MarketContainer>` that the count has changed?

Comment: you could do this by using react refs. but this would not be best way so I'll recommend you to use redux and using redux you can get data on any component.

Comment: From what I understand, you need the ‘count’ in your MarketContainer?

Comment: and one more option is you can set state in your parent component and pass callback to child component and when count change call this callback and update state in parent component.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MarketContainer extends Component {
   state = {
    count : 0
   }

   IncrementItem = () => {
   this.setState({count: count + 1})
   }

   DecreaseItem = () => {
   this.setState({count: count - 1})
   }

 render() {
const marketItems = this.state.market.map(item => <MarketItem key={item.id} 
  product={item} IncrementItem={this.IncrementItem} DecreaseItem={DecreaseItem} count={this.state.count}/>)

   return (
    <div>
      {marketItems}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

now you can use **IncrementItem** and **DecreaseItem** props on MarketItem component when user click on increment and decrement icon. also we're passing value of **count** from parent component so you can show in child component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Lifting State Up in React**

Answer (score 0):

You can define the state in MarketContainer for counts and other fields that you need to pass to other child components.

I have tried to include the codes to illustrate how I would do that.

```
   //MarketData.js
    //after ajax request
    const marketData = [

      {
        id: 1, 
        name: "product1", 
        price: "$1"
      }, 

      {
        id: 2, 
        name: "product2", 
        price: "$2"
      }
    ]; 

    //We can format market data as per we need it in components

    const formattedMarketData = marketData.map(e => {
        e.count = 0; 
        return e;
    });





  //parent component
    //let us define all the things which we might need to pass to other components in here
    // ... 

    constructor()
    {
        super(); 
        this.state = {
            markets: formattedMarketData
        }

    }

    /* we are handling all state changes in parent component
     we have updated state in parent component
     we can deliver the changed state to any other components */
    IncrementItem = (id) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const markets = {...prevState.markets}; 
            const index = markets.findIndex(x => x.id ===id);
            markets[index].count = prevState.markets[index].count + 1; 
            return {
                markets: markets
            };
        });
    }

    DecrementItem = (id) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const markets = {...prevState.markets};
            const index = markets.findIndex(x => x.id ===id);
            markets[index].count = prevState.markets[index].count - 1; 
            return {
                markets: markets
            };
        });
    }

    render() {
        const marketItems = this.state.market.map(item => <MarketItem IncrementItem={this.IncrementItem} DecrementItem={this.DecrementItem} key={item.id} product={item} />)

        return (
          <div>
              {marketItems}
          </div>
        );
      }



//child component 

export default (props) => {
 const {IncrementItem, DecreaseItem, product} = props;
 <div className="MarketItem">
        <div className="market__content">
            <h1>{product.name + " " + product.price}</h1>   
        </div> 
            <div className="market__counter">
              <button className="market__button--minus" onClick={() => {DecreaseItem(product.id)}}>-</button>
              <p>{product.count}</p>
              <button className="market__button--plus" onClick={() => {IncrementItem(product.id)}}>+</button>
            </div>

      </div>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way you should design your state to keep the count relevant to the products.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MarketItem from './MarketItem.js'

class MarketContainer extends Component {
 constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
          market:  [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "product1",
                price: "$2",
                count:0,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "product2",
                price: "$3",
                count:0,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "product3",
                price: "$3",
                count:0,
            }
        ]
    }
}

IncrementItem = (i) => {
    let market = this.state.market;
    market[i].count += 1; 
    this.setState({market});
}

DecreaseItem = (i) => {
    let market = this.state.market;
    market[i].count -= (market[i].count > 0) ? 1: 0; 
    this.setState({market});
}

render() {
    const marketItems = this.state.market.map(item => <MarketItem key={item.id} product={item}  i={i} IncrementItem={this.IncrementItem} DecreaseItem={this.DecreaseItem}/>)

    return (
      <div>
          {marketItems}
      </div>
    );
 }
}

export default MarketContainer;
```

child

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';

class MarketItem extends Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
 }

 render(){
    return (
      <div className="MarketItem">
        <div className="market__content">
            <h1>{this.props.product.name + " " + this.props.product.price}</h1>   
        </div> 
            <div className="market__counter">
              <button className="market__button--minus" onClick={() => this.props.DecreaseItem(this.props.i)}>-</button>
              <p>{this.state.count}</p>

              <button className="market__button--plus" onClick={() => this.props.IncrementItem(this.props.i)}>+</button>
            </div>

      </div>
    );
 }
}

export default MarketItem;
```